# Anyway to acquire titles of products on commerce websites through a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if it was possible for a chrome extension to do some light web scraping. In short, what I would like is for my chrome extension to be able to capture the titles of products a person is looking for.

For example, let's say I am on amazon shopping for cupcakes.

[Inspect of title from amazon listing for cupcakes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVOo8.png)

I would like to be able to take the title information "365 everyday value cupcakes..." and do something with it in the chrome extension **using javascript**.

Is this possible?

Everything I search for scraping comes back as an extension that is already developed. **I do not want something already developed, I want to program this myself!**

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/). It depends on how/whether you want to distribute it.

Comment: Do you know how a person could go about coding this themselves? Is the code for Tampermonkey available to look at anywhere?